# Confusion using path.join for __dirname in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the different between `path.join(__dirname, "src/js")` versus just `__dirname + "src/js")` in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

path.join takes cares of the / or lack of / on your strings. The second way you're doing it with pure javascript, which is ok.

```
path.join('/foo', 'bar')
```

will return /foo/bar,
but

```
'/foo' + 'bar'
```

will return /foobar which might be not where you want to access

Comment: is that all? why people type more than putting an extra '/'?

Comment: Readability more than anything.